# Cannot install Handlebars on Mac OSX

Tags: node.js, web, terminal, handlebars.js

I have downloaded and installed node.js using the .pkg file on my Mac. It is automatically installed at

```
/usr/local/bin/node
```

Then, I want to install Handlebars but I get the following error in the terminal (see picture below). I do not know how to deal with it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handlebars isn't a CLI that should be installed globally.  Install it locally in your project.

```
npm install --save handlebars
```

Comment: Yup.  In your project directory.